# How to connect & query MySQL from within Lua?

Tags: mysql, lua

How can I connect to a MySQL database from using Lua programming language?

If a good/popular library exists, what is it?

Comment: Found it: http://www.keplerproject.org/luasql/

Comment: Have you seen this: http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=5983

Answer (score 8):

Minimal woking example for [LuaSQL](https://keplerproject.github.io/luasql/manual.html) - simple interface from Lua to a DBMS.

```lua
package.cpath = package.cpath .. ";/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/lua/5.1/?.so"

luasql = require "luasql.mysql"

env = assert (luasql.mysql())
con = assert (env:connect("dbname","user","password"))
cur = assert (con:execute("SHOW TABLES"))

row = cur:fetch ({}, "a")
while row do
  print(string.format("Name: %s", row.Tables_in_dbname))
  row = cur:fetch (row, "a")
end
```

Line 1 used if module luasql.mysql not found. Also environment variable LUA_CPATH may be used.

Comment: What about if your database has a password?

Comment: @71GA At line 6. The third argument of `env:connect`.

Answer (score 5):

In case your mysql database is remote, you can add host as another optional parameter to connect. Port can follow host as well:

```
con = assert (env:connect("dbname","user","password","host",port))
```

Comment: What about password protected databases?

Comment: @71GA that is where it says 'password' - replace that with your password.

Answer (score 4):

From [LuaSQL -- Database connectivity for the Lua programming language](https://keplerproject.github.io/luasql/manual.html):

```
require "luasql.mysql"
env = assert (luasql.mysql())
con = assert (env:connect"my_db")
for id, name, address in rows (con, "select * from contacts") do
  print (string.format ("%s: %s", name, address))
end
```