# Online database in Lua/ComputerCraft

Tags: database, lua, computercraft

I want an online storage that can connect with ComputerCraft in Minecraft. ComputerCraft is Lua-based. I have heard that you can not use MySQL in Lua.

Is there some sort of online database like MySQL that I can use in Lua without installing external programs? Because I only have access to Lua computers in-game, I cannot install an external program such as LuaSQL. Is there any other way?

Comment: Heard from whom? Whoever told you that was lying. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432864/lua-how-to-connect-query-mysql-from-within-lua

Comment: ive looked at that, and now ive seen thishttp://www.keplerproject.org/luasql/, is there a way without installing other programs? because i dont have acces to the server which it runs on, only a computer ingame

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't access a MySQL database in Lua (even ComputerCraft Lua) without third party extensions.

Answer (score 0):

you could build a file read/write script and serialize a table for you Data storage... its not the best way, but it is a way that would work

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not that into web based database communication, i would guess you need an API which  delivers chunks of information asked by HTTP/HTTPS Requests. And a webserver of course.

I played a bit with CouchDB in combination with a nodejs webserver to create a very lean API with database support. So this might make the cut.
http://simonholywell.com/post/2011/10/getting-started-node-js-couch-db.html
Speeking in terms of webserver, there are several webservices like heroku that give free servers for testing etc.

Also would be very though. In combination with Applied Energistics you could monitor storage or crafting times etc.